# Jquery tooltip on dynamic image id

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using `qtip2` to generate tooltips on page images where the id changes depending on whether a user is in "create" or "edit" mode. When the `id = "how_create"` I want to generate one message, and if it's `"how_edit"` I want to generate a different one.  When I use the inspector on the image, I can see that the id does in fact change as it's supposed to.

However, I can only generate a qtip in static mode.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
$(function() { 

$('#make_tip').qtip({
 content:'Make tip',
 style: {name: 'dark', tip: 'topLeft'}
});

$('#how_create').on(function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        content:'Create',
        style: {name: 'dark', tip: 'topLeft'}
    });
});

$('#how_edit').on(function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        content:'Edit',
        style: {name: 'dark', tip: 'topLeft'}
    });
});

});
```

I get the "Make Tip" message on the static img id -- but it doesn't change to the messages linked to the dynamic image ids, even though the id is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Hrmm I haven't tried this myself but it seems like you should have an event attached to your on() function?  Like this:

```
$("#how_edit").on('click', function() {});
```

But as a solution, I would suggest looking into the .live() function.
But try this

```
$("#how_edit").live('click', function() {
  //YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Basically, the 'live' function will scan your DOM for the selector different from the "on" function which passing a selector may be a static selection.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right that it needs an event, so I used 'mouseover' as there is no link there.  Also tried 'live' but no joy. And now it doesn't pick up the static tooltip either.  Mysterious.

Comment: Wow... live() did not work?  Now thats weird...
Only thing I can say now is change your id selectors #how_edit to maybe class selectors and try if that works?  
If not, you're going to have to reinitialize the listeners on the :success callback of your live image loading part.  :(